# Why is there no water from the cold water tap on the bath?

Tags: plumbing

The cold tap in my bathroom sink has been behaving erratically over a week or 2 - slow, trickle, etc. then right off. It's now ok, but the bath cold tap stopped completely - it was ok whilst the sink tap was erratic, but since that righted itself. The bath went from ok to a trickle to nothing at all!

Comment: Welcome to SE.  We'll need more info about your taps. Single handle? 2 valves? Pictures almost always help.  Take the tour so you can best learn how to participate and contribute here.   In the meantime, probably debris in your cold feed.  Any utility work done recently, either in your home or your well, or city water supply?  Debris would settle in your water heater (assuming a tank type), but flow thru the cold to your taps.   Just a suggestion until you share more info with us.

Comment: Here's the [tour] George mentioned.